# How to use compass mixins in a project using Sass

Tags: sass, compass-sass, mixins, compass

ColorZilla's [gradient editor](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) says

> // needs latest Compass, add '@import "compass"' to your scss

Well I've found that's not so easy. Obviously if you just throw @import "compass"; at the top of your .scss file, Sass won't compile because _compass.scss can't be found.

- This is an asp.net project utilizing Sass. In addition, I have to use the sass ruby gem to compile, not compass's compiler.
- I've installed the compass gem. I've followed the instructions on http://compass-style.org/install/. I've run `compass init`, `compass create`, `compass install`. None of them even give me compass's mixins.

I expected this to work like [bourbon](http://bourbon.io/), though I know this isn't compass's primary goal.

What am I missing?

Comment: I don't understand why you're not able to use the `compass` command here.

Comment: I haven't used Compass yet but you can download the source here, https://github.com/Compass/compass/tree/stable/core/stylesheets. It has the _compass.scss and all other supporting files in the compass folder it looks like.

Comment: @cimmanon We use a VS extension which uses its own version of Sass to compile automatically. Since I just want the mixins, this shouldn't really be too much to ask for.

Comment: Do you know if is necessary install compass with SASS in 2020?

Comment: @AntonioÁngelEstradaPérez Compass is not required for Sass. It's a library for Sass. This post is about ColorZilla's gradient editor, who when generating Sass, uses Compass.

Answer (score 7):

1. Install the library

   `bower install compass-sass-mixins`
2. Import the compass into your SASS file

   `@import "bower_components/compass-sass-mixins/lib/compass"`
3. Checkout SASS function list:

   https://github.com/askucher/compass-sass-mixins

Comment: can we download scss files

Comment: @ShibinRagh, you should still be able to use the imported `.sass` library even if you are using scss. Otherwise you can use the [sass-convert](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-convert) tool (`npm install -g sass-convert`) and run `sass-convert -R ./ -F sass -T scss` from the library root directory to convert all `.sass` files  to `.scss`.