# include Compass in compiling SASS in Ionic framework?

Tags: sass, ionic2, compass-sass, compass

Does anybody knows how to include compass in an Ionic 2 project?

I have tried to import compass-sass, but I can't find a path to set the compass preprocessing in my styles.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As pointed by this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33180280/1848109) answer use this [Compass lib](https://github.com/askucher/compass-sass-mixins)

### How i implemented in my Ionic 2+ project.

- Installed via npm - `npm install compass-sass-mixins`
- Imported to my project by adding `@import "../../node_modules/compass-sass-mixins/lib/compass";` in file `app.scss`
- Then run `ionic serve`

Hope this helps to implement useful mixins